# How to resolve the Circular import Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

I am working with **phonenumbers** module in Python. I am having the issue of **circular import**. This error omits whenever I run the file from desktop location (**C:\Users\AsadA\Desktop**). But it raises an error whenever I tried to run this in a particular folder (**C:\Users\AsadA\Desktop\Python_projects\28-FindingTheNUMBER** ). Please help me!

Sample Code:

```
import phonenumbers

from phonenumbers import geocoder

from phonenumbers import carrier

from phonenumbers import timezone

my_Num=phonenumbers.parse("SAMPLE_NUM")

print(geocoder.description_for_number(my_Num,'en'))

print(carrier.name_for_number(my_Num,'en'))

print(timezone.time_zones_for_number(my_Num))
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/AsadA/Desktop/Python_projects/28-FindingTheNUMBER/phonenumbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    import phonenumbers
  File "c:\Users\AsadA\Desktop\Python_projects\28-FindingTheNUMBER\phonenumbers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from phonenumbers import geocoder
ImportError: cannot import name 'geocoder' from partially initialized module 'phonenumbers' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\AsadA\Desktop\Python_projects\28-FindingTheNUMBER\phonenumbers.py)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might probably named your file as **"phonenumber.py"**. If you are importing something in python, please make sure that file name is not same as imported file. If it is same, then it will create an error.
This happens due to same name conflict with imported file as imported file name is also the same. And if this occur then python always give priority to file with current directory you are working.
So, let say your code is something like below.

```
import xyz
print(xyz.version)
```

And your file name is "xyz.py". Python compiler now sees that there are two files of same name "xyz.py", one in script folder where python is installed and another in current directory we are working. So, python compiler compiler choose file to import from current directory you are working on.
So, python read first line import xyz, it imports the file from current directory which means it import again this file and start reading it. In that, again first line is import xyz, then it again imports xyz in current folder causing a loop to occur.
This is called as **circular loop**.


**So, in short, changing your file name can solve the problem.**

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the module phonenumbers using 'import phonenumbers' and then you are importing the relevant definitions inside that module in the next few lines. They are redundant.

Fixed code:

```
import phonenumbers

my_Num=phonenumbers.parse("SAMPLE_NUM")

print(phonenumbers.geocoder.description_for_number(my_Num,'en'))

print(phonenumbers.carrier.name_for_number(my_Num,'en'))

print(phonenumbers.timezone.time_zones_for_number(my_Num))
```

Or something like this:

```
from phonenumbers import (
    parse,
    geocoder,
    carrier,
    timezone,
)

my_Num=parse("SAMPLE_NUM")

print(geocoder.description_for_number(my_Num,'en'))

print(carrier.name_for_number(my_Num,'en'))

print(timezone.time_zones_for_number(my_Num))
```

Comment: Not working still conflicting an error:                                                                                         AttributeError: partially initialized module 'phonenumbers' has no attribute 'parse' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Did you try the second solution?